# 2-column matrix from 2 vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

This feels like it should be simple.

I am building a minimum distance classifier and I want to put feature1 and feature2 into the same matrix so that I can call them and get answers like this.

`featureVector(1,:) =` all the `feature1` values

`featureVector(2,:) =` all the `feature2` values

I'm looping through and hoping to put these values into the `featureVector` as the loop runs.

I'm fairy new to MATLAB so i'm not sure how to put that into words. Hopefully that makes enough sense.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `feature1` is a horizontal vector, then do:

```
featureVector = [ feature1 ; feature2 ]
```

Else (if vertical), do:

```
featureVector = [ feature1 , feature2 ]
```

If you don't know it's orientation, you can always do a `reshape`:

```
feature1 = reshape(feature1, 1, numel(feature1))
```

... what will make `feature1` horizontal, or:

```
feature1 = reshape(feature1, numel(feature1), 1)
```

... what will make `feature1` vertical.

`reshape` used like that will make horizontal/vertical vector from *any* vector/matrix, taking particular values one-by-one from the original source.

**Edit**: A proof that it works:

```
>> a = [1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5];
>> b = [6 ; 7 ; 8 ; 9 ; 10];
>> ab = [a, b]

ab =

     1     6
     2     7
     3     8
     4     9
     5    10

>> ab(2,:)

ans =

     2     7
```

**Edit**: If your `feature1` and `feature2` are scalars, and you want to add them to the `featureVector` one-by-one in every iteration, then do:

```
featureVector = []

for i = 1:...
    feature1 = ...;
    feature2 = ...;
    featureVector = [featureVector; [feature1, feature2]];
end
```

Comment: That was my initial try. When I do the first option up there, it only keeps the last 2 values of feature1 and feature2. I need it to keep them all. It outputs a 2x1 matrix after the loop and it should be 5x1.

Comment: ratio=h1_max/h2_max;
    
formant3 = formfreq(1);
formant4 = formfreq(2);
    
formDistance = formant4 - formant3;
   
featureVector1 = [ratio, formDistance];

Comment: Change the last line to: `featureVector1 = [reshape(ratio, numel(ratio), 1), reshape(formDistance, numel(formDistance), 1)];`, as I've suggested at the beginning.

Comment: Now i'm getting a 1x2 matrix instead of 2x1. I copy and pasted it. Maybe it's another line after that messing it up? I have featureVector1 = []; up before the loop starts.

Comment: I believe it's right, I just haven't gotten it yet. I'll accept this once I do.

Comment: Hey, if you want 1x2, then forget about reshape. But you'll have to access the values like that: `featureVector1(:,i)` instead of `(i,:)`. See what's in `ratio` and `formDistance` (remove the `;` from their lines). They're probably 1-element vectors. :-)

Comment: My variables ratio and formDistance are just scalars, not vectors. How does that affect it, if at all?

Comment: How would you like to get 5x2 matrix from two scalars? Impossible.

Comment: Each time I iterate through the loop, I calculate a new value of ratio and formDistance. So I want to calculate a ratio and formDistance for k=1, store it in featureVector1, iterate through with k=2 and store those values of ratio and formDistance in featureVector1 and so on..

Comment: Ok, then in each iteration you should do: `featureVector1 = [featureVector1; [ratio, formDistance]]`. And before the `for` loop, you should initialize `featureVector1 = []`.

Comment: There it is! I was so close, I didn't have the syntax of the ratio/formDistance values correct. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using this?

```
results = [values1,values2];
```